# Interpreting very high conditional and very low marginal R^2 in linear mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-model, variance, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I've fit a linear random slope mixed effect model to some time series data from multiple participants. Here time is the fixed effect and participant is the random effect. I've received a very high conditional R^2 (~.99) and a very small marginal R^2 (~.01). I'd like some advice on how to interpret this.

Thus far my understanding is this. The high conditional R^2 suggests most of my variance is in between my random effect levels (in this instance this is the different time-series of different participants). That is, to fit the models well, I have to alter the coefficients pretty drastically per participant.

Given that roughly 98% of the variance is being accounted for by adjusting the coefficients, it seems to me that a value of 1% is actually quite high for the marginal R^2. That is, once you ignore the differences between participants, roughly half of the variance is accounted for. Is this an appropriate way to think about this?

Another way of thinking of what I mean (this seems pretty abstract to me as it is) is that if I was only looking at one participant with multiple sets of time series observations, the random effect variance should now not be present, therefore the variance account for would be higher because overall there is less variation?

Concisely, is my marginal R^2 fine despite being very small but has been squashed down because of just how much variability is between my participants?

Comment: "*Given that roughly 98% of the variance is being accounted for by adjusting the coefficients, it seems to me that a value of 1% is actually quite high for the marginal R^2*". This doesn't seem like the best way to think about this. Setting aside the random effects for the moment, whether an R^2 value is high or low depends very much on the question or field. So we can't assess that for you without knowing more about the specifics (and we may not be able to even then).

Comment: Secondly, I'd generally be suspicious if I ever fit a model that explained 100% of the variance. That would lead me to inspect the model and data to see if there was some error or basic problem that I was missing.

Comment: What software did you use to fit the model ?

Comment: The field is behavioural finance. Behavioural data with the added noises of the stock market.

It is indeed suspicious however I cannot find any real reason to criticise the data going into the model. The model is fit in R and uses a formula of:

Predicted ~ time + time^2 + ( time | time-series) + (time^2 | time-series)

So it's being fit to a quadratic curve but all the coefficients may vary per time series.